# syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'

Tags: php

While trying to echo out a line, get an unexpected error for the following line:

```
echo "$arr[count($arr)]".')';
```

Cannot figure out what the fix might be. Want to print out the last item of the array.

Comment: remove your double quotes

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about minimal efforts to spend on debugging

Comment: PHP doesn’t allow arbitrary expressions in double-quoted strings. Remove the `"` and you’re fine.

Comment: When removing the "" I get the following error:  Undefined offset

Comment: Look at @crazyh answer for that. Do `count($arr) - 1` as index starts at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes and remember that array index starts from zero.

```
echo $arr[count($arr) - 1];
```

Or just:

```
echo end($arr);
```

Comment: Yes, a rookie mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo '('.$arr[count($arr)].')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo $arr[count($arr)];
```